# Wrap text in tables by number of lines

Tags: css

I have a table with one table row and four columns. Each column contains an image, a header and a paragraph. I want to cut the paragraphs at line 7 in each column so that the text in each of them is aligned horizontally. Think of this as a "read more" case of scenario.

I have looked into:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
```

This cuts the paragraph at the first line. Is there any way to cut the paragraph at a specific line with CSS?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.box {
  padding: 2em;
  width: 200px;
}

.box p {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

> for "three" specific line (  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;)

```
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: block-axis 
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
```